# Flutter & firebase - StreamBuilder not loading

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-streambuilder

My code was working fine. As soon as I added `isEqualTo`, the app keeps on loading and loading.

I am guessing perhaps I do have to do something with RULES in FirebaseFirestore. Not sure though. And also I know nothing of rules.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: _firebaseFirestore
    .collection('wallpapers')
    .where('uploadedBy', isEqualTo: _user!.uid)
    .orderBy('date', descending: true)
    .snapshots(),
)
```

Comment: make sure to print if there are any errors, my guess is your query needs an index.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Pretty new to Flutter & Firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your builder

```
if (snapShot.hasError) {
  print(snapShot.error);
  return new Text('Error: ${snapShot.error}');
}
```

then it will probably print you the link in which you will be able to build your index with. If that's not the case make sure there exists a data that satisfies your query.

Comment: Indeed I got a link in the terminal. It took me to cloud platform and solved the issue :) Thanks